# HTML5 sorting DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a little problem with HTML5 drag&drop API.
Let's write the code so everyone can understand.

```
<div id="draggerContainer" droppable="true">
  <div class="draggableItem" draggable="true" data-id="001">[... Stuff inside like <img> and other <div> ...] </div>
  <div class="draggableItem" draggable="true" data-id="002">[... Stuff inside like <img> and other <div> ...] </div>
  <div class="draggableItem" draggable="true" data-id="003">[... Stuff inside like <img> and other <div> ...] </div>
  <div class="draggableItem" draggable="true" data-id="004">[... Stuff inside like <img> and other <div> ...] </div>
  <div class="draggableItem" draggable="true" data-id="005">[... Stuff inside like <img> and other <div> ...] </div>
  <div class="draggableItem" draggable="true" data-id="006">[... Stuff inside like <img> and other <div> ...] </div>
</div>
```

Well that's is awkard but I don't know how to use the drag&drop api. I've already tried the tutorial on html5rocks.com but nothing.. Can someone tell me how to start and create a sorting system in html5 and Js (better jQuery if is possible) ?

That's the source code from the tutorial.

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
  // Target (this) element is the source node.
  this.style.opacity = '0.4';
  dragSrcEl = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}
function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
  return false;
}
function handleDragEnter(e) {
  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
  this.classList.add('over');
}
function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over');  // this / e.target is previous target element.
}
function handleDrop(e) {
  // this / e.target is current target element.
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
  }
  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
  return false;
}
function handleDragEnd(e) {
  // this/e.target is the source node.
  [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
    col.classList.remove('over');
  });
}
var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#draggerContainer .draggableItem');
[].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
  col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
  col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

I've used Javascript scripts  used in tutorial on [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/).

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Where is your JS / JQuery source? You can't just post static HTML and ask why the JS is broken. Any console output, etc?

Comment: that's the Js source http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: If you are asking for a tutorial that you can't execute without success I think this is not the right place. You have to put code that makes your life a nightmare or something. So, if you did that tutorial, what you think is wrong? where are you getting an error? These could be reasonable questions (also, providing some code)

Comment: I don't want a tutorial.. I've already use it (HTML5ROCKS). I wonder if someone can just help me.

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta You don't get my point of view. Can you please put some code to take a look and help you?

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta: That tutorial is not just a tutorial but also shows you all the code that's required to make draggable objects. If you've implemented it on your page step by step it should work as well. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The answer belove this question is what I need btw. I'm only a little noob who need some help with html5 and jQuery. Apologize me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WxTqd/

First, when a drag starts, send the `data-id` attribute as drag information, so that you know which element is being dragged:

```
$("#draggerContainer")
    .on("dragstart", ".draggableItem", function(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData("id", $(this).data("id"));
    })
```

You have to `preventDefault()` on `dragover` to get drag working:

```
.on("dragover", ".draggableItem", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

And on `drop`, you have to swap elements:

```
.on("drop", ".draggableItem", function(e) {
    // get the element being dragged according to drag information
    var id = e.dataTransfer.getData("id");

    var $draggingElem = $(".draggableItem").filter(function() {
        return $(this).data("id") === id;
    });


    // This is to make sure the element appears under the cursor
    var indexDrag = $draggingElem.index();
    var indexThis = $(this).index();

    if(indexDrag < indexThis) {
        $draggingElem.insertAfter(this);
    } else if(indexDrag > indexThis) {
        $draggingElem.insertBefore(this);
    }
});
```

This uses `e.dataTransfer`, which jQuery doesn't expose by default. To enable this, execute this once per page load:

```
$.event.props.push("dataTransfer");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it ASAP

Comment: Just want to add that you can also get to dataTransfer on a jQuery event object like this: `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer` It's a bit less direct, but it doesn't require the event props push.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jquery ui sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable)

It's a pretty simple library

Comment: JQuery UI Sortable works for simple UL's. But when you need to drag drop div's or other elements it doesn't work as expected.